# Trumpet type or technique?

Tags: sheet-music, instruments, brass, trumpet, orchestration

In Wagner’s “Rule, Britannia”, the orchestration calls for two trumpets.

[image: trumpets]
I’ve had no luck searching for what “vent.” and “ord.” mean.   “Open” and “muted”, or ...?

Comment: I trust on my feeling for languages and looked up *ventura* and *ordinata* but couldn’t find something reasonable. Now I’m sure vent stands for ventil and ord. = ordinaria.

Comment: Even this a very rare problem I vote for it as I didn’t know the answer quite promptly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Vent.* is an abbreviation for *Ventil*, which is the German for *valve*.

*Ord.* probably denotes *ordinary*, for *non*-valved trumpets, i.e. bugles.

If you look through the Vent. parts, they do feature chromatic notes, which would require valves. The Ord. parts are all bugle notes, except these bugles have a lowest open note which is an octave lower than today's common D trumpet.

Comment: I didn’t see your answer but now as I’ve posted mine and see yours I bet we are right. +1

Comment: Dolmetsch agrees with you.    Trumpet players should be aware that "ord" in the middle of a piece can mean to remove a previously inserted mute.  Clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 5):

I just can guess:

Tromba ord. means *ordinaria* and will stand for natural trumpet.

Tromba vent. stands for *ventil*, these are piston trumpets with valves.